# map server problems

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I wonted to load a map from a bag file using the map server but I could not. First I played the bag file during running the master with roscore. After finishind the play of the bag file in new tab i tried to load the map with rosrun map_server map_saver -f /filename

But I was waiting for the map and nothing. Any help??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56898/map-server-problems/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [map_saver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/map_server#map_saver) saves the map published on `/map` to a file.

The [map_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/map_server#map_server-1) loads a map and publishes it (latched) on `/map`.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-04-11**:
ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even though this question is quite old: You have to run the map_saver while the bag is still playing. If you start it after the bag has finished, there are no messages on the /map topic for the map_saver to capture and save.

If you want to make sure, that you only get the latest map messages out of the bag, use the following procedure:

- Use `rosbag info` to determine the length of your bag in seconds
- Start a `roscore`and run the `map_saver` with the appropriate topic set
- Play your bag file with `rosbag play -s x bagfile.bag` where `x` is the duration of your bag minus 3-5 seconds. (Depends on the rate at which the map is published. If it does not get a map, try to subtract longer timespans)

This way you dont have to manually start the saver at the latest possible moment. :)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-04-11**:
ok. Thanks